# Performance when filtering after $geoNear query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection which contains a location (GeoJSON Point) and other fields to filter on.

```
{
        "Location" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                        -118.42359,
                        33.974563
                ]
        },
        "Filters" : [
                {
                        "k" : 1,
                        "v" : 5
                },
                {
                        "k" : 2,
                        "v" : 8
                }
        ]
}
```

My query uses the aggregate function because it performs a sequence of filtering, sorting, grouping, etc... The first step where it's filtering is where I'm having trouble performing the geo near operation.

```
$geoNear: {
                        spherical: true,
                        near: [-118.236391, 33.782092],
                        distanceField: 'Distance',
                        query: {
                            // Filter by other fields.
                            Filters: {
                                $all: [
                                    { $elemMatch: { k: 1 /* Bedrooms */, v: 5 } }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        maxDistance: 8046
                    },
```

For indexing I tried two approaches:

Approach #1: Create two separate indexes, one with the Location field and one with the fields we subsequently filter on. This approach is slow, with very little data in my collection it takes 3+ seconds to query within a 5 mile radius.

```
db.ResidentialListing.ensureIndex( { Location: '2dsphere' }, { name: 'ResidentialListingGeoIndex' } );
db.ResidentialListing.ensureIndex( { "Filters.k": 1, "Filters.v": 1 }, { name: 'ResidentialListingGeoQueryIndex' } );
```

Approach #2: Create one index with both the Location and other fields we filter on. Creating the index never completed, as it generated a ton of warnings about "Insert of geo object generated a high number of keys".

```
db.ResidentialListing.ensureIndex( { Location: '2dsphere', "Filters.k": 1, "Filters.v": 1 }, { name: 'ResidentialListingGeoIndex' } );
```

The geo index itself seems to work fine, if I only perform the $geoNear operation and don't try to query after then it executes in 60ms. However, as soon as I try to query on other fields after is when it gets slow. Any ideas would be appreciated on how to set up the query and indexes correctly so that it performs well...